# MVC misconception

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, architecture, software-design

I started learning ASP.NET MVC recently, and as far as I understood:

- **Model** represents a structure of the app data;
- **View** represents user interface;
- **Controller** handles actions between the model and the view.

But the first statement in the [Wikipedia article for MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) states that:

> Model–view–controller (MVC) is a software architectural pattern for implementing **user interfaces** on computers.

This looks ambiguous to me. Isn't the the user interface implemented with the "V part" of MVC, or I'm missing something!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a whole the goal of an MVC application is to provide the user with an interface. All the different components are simply there to organize the code in a consistent manner accross the application.

As stated in wikepedia, each component serves a purpose with a goal of giving the user an output (view) for data (model) with commands (controller).

So the View is not a user interface, it is an output for the model. the user interface is the whole.

Comment: Oh.. Now it makes sense. Thank you a lot! :)